# Throw the correct message when there are 2 `catch`es

Tags: javascript

```
    elementX.isPresent()
        .then(() => {

              elementX.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click()

                  .catch(error => {
                        throw {message: "Unable to select text in dropdown box"}
                    })

        })
        .catch (error => {
                throw {message : "element is not present"}

        })
```

I want to throw 2 different error messages 1. If element is missing 2. Given text is missing in the dropdown.

If element is missing, error is thrown correctly. But if element is present, and the given text is missing, still "element is not present" is thrown. How should the code be changed to throw the other error message?

I tried

```
  elementX.isPresent()
 .then(
    _ => elementX.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click()
          .then(() => {
                     console.log("hello")
          })
         .catch(_ => { throw {message: "Unable to select text in dropdown box"} }),
    _ => { throw {message : "element is not present"} }
  )
```

as suggested here and that did not work- returned only the last catch message

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example. Looking at what you tried it seems the problem is now somewhere else. Are you maybe using a promise library that does not comply with the specification or maybe `elementX.isPresent()` always throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest for your example would be:

```
elementX.isPresent()
  .then(
    _ => elementX.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click()
           .catch(_ => { throw {message: "Unable to select text in dropdown box"} }),
    _ => { throw {message : "element is not present"} }
```

### )

**Update**

An example that you can test in the console:

```
elementIsPresent.then(
  _ => Promise.reject().then(_ => {}).catch(_ => { throw { e: '1' } }),
  _ => { throw { e: '2' } }
)
```

Before you execute the above code set the following:

```
elementIsPresent = Promise.resolve()
```

The result of executing the snippet above will be a rejection with `{ e: '1' }`. Then you can set the following:

```
elementIsPresent = Promise.reject()
```

If you apply the snippet once you have this set the result will be a rejection with `{ e: '2' }`.

Comment: that does not work. Still it throws the error from the first catch only

Comment: Can you add the new code to your original question (keep the original code there as well to help other people in the future)? My best guess without looking at your code is that you are not returning the promise to the first part of the `then`.

Comment: @user3920295, what was the problem?